# Jenkins URL port Context issue

Tags: jenkins

I am configuring Jenkins on Windows machine, I installed and working fine. I want change Context of the URL , i tried adding argument in Jenkins .xml but it didn't work, please help me on this

how to set  context in jenkins.msi  http://localhost:8080/Jenkins instead of http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F

Answer (score 0):

Add **`--prefix={/NewRootContext}`** in the arguments tag on **jenkins.xml** to update the root context.

example :

```
 <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war" --prefix="/Jenkins"</arguments>
```